# check if any three consecutive transactions are over a specified amount

Tags: sql, teradata

There is a table which has data about the transactions of all the customers in a bank.

In case of the theft of the card (say debit), the miscreant is likely to withdraw as much money as he can in small chunks to avoid suspicion. So the bank wants to know if any three consecutive transactions exceed 10000 then its a fraud.

There can be 100 transactions in a day per customer but only consecutive three(any three- may be 1,2,3 or 7,8,9 etc) per customer per day will be considered.

The table has data as following:

```
cid trans_date  trans_time  amount
1   1/15/2018    9:21:33     4000
1   1/15/2018    9:21:34    12000
1   1/15/2018    9:35:33    11000
1   1/15/2018   10:21:33    10000
2   2/17/2018   11:21:33    10000
2   2/18/2018    9:21:33    10000
2   3/18/2018    9:21:33    10000
3   1/15/2018    9:23:33     4000
3   1/15/2018    9:24:33     9000
3   1/15/2018    9:25:33    10000
3   1/15/2018    9:26:33    14000
3   1/15/2018    9:27:33     4000
3   2/18/2018    9:21:33    10000
3   2/18/2018    9:22:33    13000
4   1/15/2018    9:21:33     4000
4   1/15/2018    9:22:33    10000
4   1/15/2018    9:23:33    12000
4   1/15/2018    9:24:33     4000
4   1/15/2018    9:25:33     2000
4   1/15/2018    9:26:33    60000
4   1/15/2018    9:27:33    10000
```

Output should be cid which satisfy the above condition: cid 1. cid 2 shouldn't be considered since the only two consecutive transactions happened in a day. 3 and 4 of course don't satisfy the condition.

I tried the following query but it didn't give the desired result.

```
select distinct bb.cid 
from
    (
        select
            cid,
            count(case when amount>=10000 then 1 else 0 end) 
                over(partition by cid,trans_date order by trans_time rows between current row and 2 following)
            cn
        from testtable ) bb 
where cn >= 3
```

I am using Teradata v16 database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COUNT counts non-NULL values, but your CASE always returns a value (*0/1*). Either remove the `else 0` or switch to `SUM`. Additionally you can get rid of the *Derived Table* using QUALIFY:

```
select distinct cid
from testtable
qualify 
   SUM(case when amount>=10000 then 1 else 0 end) 
   over(partition by cid, trans_date order by trans_time 
        rows 2 preceding) = 3
```